# How to avoid using `extra` when retrieve data from postgres?

Tags: django, orm, django-orm

I'm retrieving data from postgres DB with following code:

```py
values = ('foo', 'bar', 'group')

FooBar.objects.order_by('-id').extra(select={'group': "'stackoverflow'"}).values(*values)
```

The code works fine but I've heard that using `extra` is not preferable and even django documentations says to “Use this method as a last resort.” So the question is how it's possible to avoid using `extra` to retrieve data?

Comment: What's the point of doing this in the query at all? You're just selecting a constant string.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I need to have this constant in queryset as per API requirements. And it must be a queryset object because DRF pagination doesn't accept non queryset objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [Value()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions) expressions. Basically when you need to represent the value of an integer, boolean, or string within an expression, you can wrap that value within a Value().

```
from django.db.models import Value, CharField
FooBar.objects.annotate(group=Value('stackoverflow', output_field=CharField())).values('foo', 'bar', 'group').order_by('-id')
```

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I needed. Tnx!